# How to query Firebase by attribute of a child?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Schema:

[image: Schema:]

I'm trying to get all the objects filter by owner

To get a specific I do this:

```
var refCompaniesById = firebase.database().ref('companies').child(id);
```

But in this case I wanted to filter all

I tried:

```
ref.child('companies').child().set({"owner": id})
```

But I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
firebase.database().ref('companies').orderByChild('owner').equalTo(id)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    const records = snapshot.val();
    console.log(`Companies whose owner id is ${id}: `, records);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be done with a Firebase Database query:

```
var query = ref.child("companies").orderByChild("owner").equalTo(id);
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

This and more is covered in the [Firebase Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), but I also recommend [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the angularfire documentation. Firebase for sql developers is wonderful, I did not know

Comment: AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase Javascript SDK. For anything that is not directly related to binding data to the AngularJS UI, refer to the JavaScript SDK documentation.